# Combine text Editors in visual studio

Tags: php, visual-studio, text-editor

I have to create a project in php. I am very used to the visual studio ide therefore it will be very nice if I could program my site in there. There is a plug in that enables you to create php projects in visual studio located in [here](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php).

When I open a php file it is great, I get the intelicence and code coloring.

[image]

the problem is that when I see the other parts of that page (html, javascript, css etc) I dont get the intelligence nor the dom help where I can select elements etc.

so javascript appears as:

[image]

to resolve this problem of the javascript and intelicence I told visual studio to treat php files as html by doing:

Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> File Extension
[image]

after doing that I am able to get the intelicence on the html, javascript, css etc. but then I lose the php functionality.

It will be very nice if I could make this work with visual studio. I have to do this project in php I wish I had to do it on asp. So I was thinking that maybe I could combine the editors since the php editor only cares about what is inside  and html about the rest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the popular and excellent [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), it is best to separate your HTML and PHP. This will solve more problems than just editor support.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I never thought about separating php and html. I don't know anything about MVC though... I will give it a try